# How to escape quotes "" characters in MySQL and Java

Tags: java, mysql

How can we escape `quotes` `""` characters in Java and MySQL?

An incoming XML file has quotes, and I am parsing through that file using Java. So I want to escape the quotes here, but in the database it should contain quotes. When I am doing a query the result would have quotes. While displaying on a webpage it should also show quotes.

Comment: That's not playing fair to edit your question (adding "and MySQL") and move the goalposts.

Comment: I see you just added the MySQL qualifier to your question. Can you be more specific about the precise problem? Is there a particular SQL query you're trying to execute from Java?

Comment: I guess I should have placed it as comments about MySQL

Comment: Incoming xml file has quotes and am parsing through that file using java and so i want to escape quotes here but in database it should contain quotes and while am doing query the result would have quotes and while displaying on webpage also it should show quotes. Hope am making my self bit clear

Comment: I did not want to open new question for it.

Comment: You're asking a bunch of different questions. XML escaping, Java escaping, SQL escaping and escaping for "webpages" (which could be a combination of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS, for example) are all different.

Comment: Still very unclear. Actually it's far less clear now. Can you show a sample input and a sample output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me try and understand...

The incoming file has quotes in it. You want to send it to a database. When you get it back from the database then you still want those quotes to be there.

So is it just to/from the database that you are having your issue?

If so then I *highly* suspect you are doing something on the order of:  (I'm wrapping it in a disclaimer to keep the unsuspecting from misunderstanding and cutting/pasting into their own applications. ;))

### Bad - do not do this

```
String sql = "insert into foo (bar,baz) values(" +myValue1 + ", " + myValue2 + ")";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

### Bad - do not do that

If so then you should really be using prepared statement's parameters at a minimum. a) you will be less vulnerable to malicious garbage deleting all of your tables, and b) you will not have any escaping problems.

```
String sql = "insert into foo (bar, baz) values( ?, ? )";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, myValue1);
stmt.setString(2, myValue2);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Note that it's also safer in the case of things like CLOBs and the specifics of different database implementations (I'm thinking of you, Oracle >))

If it is some other kind of escaping, that is, to/from XML or to/from HTML then that's different, but it is well documented all over the web.

Or provide some example code if I'm totally off base.

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you! I was having issues with escape characters in a very similar situation and was wondering also about SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Talk about killing two birds with one stone, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The typical escape character for pretty much *anything* is the backslash `\`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
\"
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

Anything (OK, not anything), but most characters use

```
 \
```

as the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious (and best) thing to do is what everyone else suggested. A goofy alternative is to put the double quote inside a single quote:

```
String quotedText = '"' + "A quick brown fox..." + '"';
```