# Escaping quotes

Tags: java

I'm trying to save a String to a database, I need the quotes to be part of the string:

```
String password = "\"foo\"";
```

I am expecting the value in the database to be `"foo"` (quotes included) 
However the slash is also stored. Should the slash be just a escape character and not be saved when compiled?

Comment: What are you using to view the database?

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878027/how-to-escape-quotes-characters-in-mysql-and-java

Comment: What type of DB is it? How are you viewing at its contents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However the slash is also stored.

Not in the string you've posted it isn't. The string you've posted has five characters in it:

```
"
f
o
o
"
```

It may be that whatever you're using to view it is showing the quotes escaped so that it's clear that they're not delimiting the string.

You can prove this like so:

```
public class ShowString {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "\"foo\"";
        int    index, len;

        for (index = 0, len = password.length(); index < len; ++index) {
            System.out.println("[" + index + "]: " + password.charAt(index));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0]: "
[1]: f
[2]: o
[3]: o
[4]: "
```